# Jersey / char [] : HTTP error 415 : Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, jersey

I'm using Jersey to expose a REST API.

I get HTTP error 415 : Unsupported Media Type when I try to send a request to the following entry point :

```
  @POST
  @Path("check")
  @Produces("application/json")
  Response checkPassword(char[] password);
```

But when I turn my password into String, It works fine :

```
  Response checkPassword(String password);
```

The idea of using a `char[]` is to apply some good practices as stated here : [Why is char[] preferred over String for passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords)

Does anyone knows why I get 415 with `char []` ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post your POST request?

As the message tells it is the mediatype of the request which is not supported.

```
@Consumes("application/json")
```

which type of data you expect. This could be json (then you normally wrap this into some object, or text/plain or xml or whatever you like but currently the type jersey expects is not matching the transfered type either on request or response.